# Add icons to menu items when showAsAction="never"

Tags: android, xml, menu

I have items in a menu, this is one of them

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:title="Settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"/>
```

And my menu appears like this...

[image: My menu preview]

But I want the icons to show up like this menu

[image: target menu]

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inflating your menu item like this below, it is working for me:

```java
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        if(menu instanceof MenuBuilder){
            MenuBuilder m = (MenuBuilder) menu;
            //noinspection RestrictedApi
            m.setOptionalIconsVisible(true);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use MenuBuilder.setOptionalIconsVisible(true) in onCreateOptionsMenu

```
MenuBuilder m = (MenuBuilder) menu;
m.setOptionalIconsVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have 2 solutions**

```
 < item
              android:id="@+id/action_add_contact"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
              android:title="Add contact"
              app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

**Or add menu items programmatically**

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_patient_home_screen, menu);

        menu.add(0, 1, 1, menuIconWithText(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.user_2), getResources().getString(R.string.action_profile)));
        menu.add(0, 2, 2, menuIconWithText(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.add_user), getResources().getString(R.string.action_add_user)));
        menu.add(0, 3, 3, menuIconWithText(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.switch_profile), getResources().getString(R.string.action_switch_profile)));
        menu.add(0, 4, 4, menuIconWithText(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.logout), getResources().getString(R.string.action_sign_out)));
        return true;
    }
```